# iOS: Full width custom titleView of navigation bar flickers during interactive pop gesture of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to use a custom titleView for my navigation controller which occupies available width in navigation bar. To achieve this I'm using a custom view with UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize as it's intrinsicContentSize.
But due to this layoutFittingExpandedSize the title view flickers during interactive pop gesture of UINavigationController. (Please see attached GIF: https://ibb.co/98hC3rc )

Note: I'm having a default navigation back bar button and a custom right bar button item.

- This can be fixed if the title view has fixed width. But calculating the available space for title view in navigation bar is not possible.
- I've also tried toggling `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag in view controller life cycle method, but it does not work.

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let searchBox = SearchView(frame: .zero)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBox

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}

class SearchView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me solve this title view flickering issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution to this.
The interactive pop gesture starts at `viewWillDisappear:` and ends at `viewWillAppear:`.
Step 1: switch on `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for navigation title view when interaction starts(i.e. in `viewWillDisappear:`) so that the width and position of title view remains constant.
Step 2: switch off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for navigation title view when interaction stops(i.e. in `viewWillAppear:`) so that the existing constraints will work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from using Auto Layout instead? You could listen to when `titleView` gets added to a superview, and set up your constraints then (though make sure to only do it once).

Comment: To use AutoLayout constraints we need sibling views(i.e. left and right bar button items) which are unavailable to us when titleView is added to superview and their inter-item spacing which is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so the solution is:

1. Create your own class for TitleView (you already have it: `class SearchView: UIView {}`)
2. Override `intrinsicContentSize` (You may rely on `UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize` but it can be
   different on iOS 15 and iOS 16 for example, and then to have the same
   left/right margins you will need to rely on `UIScreen.main.bounds` instead.)
3. In ViewController where you have your `SearchTitleView` you need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of your custom `searchTitleView` equal true/false to prevent jumping and overlapping navigation bar button items, like this:

```html
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    searchTitleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    searchTitleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
}
```

And, finally, it will look better w/o your and mine issue.